# WCF force service timeout and throttling

Tags: .net, wcf, throttling

I have a WCF service method that takes a long time to run. For the sake of explanation, let’s say sometimes it takes 0.5 seconds and the other time it takes 5 seconds. The time to process each request varies from 0.5 to 5 seconds. There is a business condition that says if the service can’t handle the request within 2 seconds the client will consider it as failure and consider sending the request to another server.

Let’s say the service gets 10 concurrent requests, out of which 4 succeed because the service manages to execute them in less than 2 seconds and the remaining 6 fail. The problem I face is that the remaining 6 is doing something that the client is not going to consume. Since this 6 request consume server resources the new incoming request get delayed. Overtime you see more and more request being considered as failed simply because the WCF queues requests that no one is going to use once processed.

How can I instruct the WCF throttling/timeout to terminate the current request if it fails to execute the web method/the request within let’s say within 3 seconds from the time it receives the request.  This should not be a client side setting. I want to instruct the service like “If you can’t serve the request within let’s say 4 seconds just forget about it and stop servicing that request because no one is going to use your end result”.

I have played around with ServiceThrottlingBehavior and (CloseTimeout,OpenTimeout,SendTimeout,ReceiveTimeout) but nothing help to tell the service to stop processing after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Some info on implementing a timer and abort mechanism [here](http://mohundro.com/blog/2011/08/19/wcf-and-service-side-timeouts/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974640/why-doesnt-wcf-support-service-side-timeouts). AFAIK wrapping this in a  TransactionScope timeout [won't help either](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/transaction-timeout-in-systemtransactions/)

Comment: Is a work expected to be done in 2 seconds executed in sync or async way?

Comment: Part of 2 seconds is executed in sequential manner (internal lock). Otherwise the service is configured to execute in multi threaded way.     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,