# WCF Timeouts - Is the thread killed or allowed to complete

Tags: wcf, timeout

Say I have the following chain of execution in my WCF Service:

ServiceMethod calls and waits for Method1, then calls and waits for Method2, which calls and waits for Method3.  Finally ServiceMethod calls and waits for Method4 before returning.

What happens if the service's configured timeout is hit during the execution of Method 3 (or any of those methods)?  Does the thread executing ServiceMethod just get terminated immediately? With no further execution?  Or does the process allow the thread to continue to the end, without returning any result?

My concern is in knowing how far processing went before the timeout was encountered.  If the thread is allowed to complete, then one can know that all completed anyway (even though no result was returned).  But if the thread just gets terminated immediately, one would have to design the ServiceMethod so that one can trace how far it got, and then try again from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation is allowed to run to completion on the server - it's the WCF channel that times out. In fact, some people have asked here for a way to force the server side processing to abort when a timeout occurs, and it's generally agreed that doing that cleanly would be difficult:

[Why doesn’t WCF support service-side timeouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974640/why-doesnt-wcf-support-service-side-timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

After the service instance has been created by the host, it will continue to run until either process is terminated, your logic completes and exits the entry point (operation) or uncaught exception is thrown. The timeout you are concerned with is between the client and the host.

Client will get an exception on the channel signalling the timeout as the channel fault. This tells the client that channel is not safe for use and it will have to be re-created.

Small comment on the call chain. You are better of encapsulate your step by step logic in a single workflow or manager which can help you with requirements for re-startability or compensation logic. Have a single entry point in your service which then can execute the workflow.

+1 on the answer for Why doesn't WCF support service-side timeouts from "500-internal server"