# Current thread works even service time out?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have created a wcf service in order to test wcf time outs. my problem is even time out has expired its still works.

In this service i have created long running method and in there i create log file,then i let to service time out.but even service time out has expired still log file appending data till to the long running method finish execution.?

How this happen? are there is a way to stop that ?

> service timeout is 1 min
>
> long running method duration is :10 mins
>
> This service hosted in IIS 7.5 using WAS

here is the my service implementation class

```
public class LongRunner : ILongRunner
{
    public void LongRunnerMethod()
    {
        int counter = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["val"]);
        string text = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; true; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (i >= counter)
                break;
            text = string.Concat(i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Looger\log.txt", text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the my service interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILongRunner
{
    [OperationContract]
    void LongRunnerMethod();
}
```

Finally here is the web config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="val" value="600"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ORServiceBehavior" name="PTS.LongRunner">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultNetTcpBinding" name="ORServiceTCPEndPoint"
                contract="PTS.ILongRunner" address="" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8079/___/_________.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultNetTcpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <reliableSession enabled="false" ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ORServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="50000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>

   </configuration>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn’t WCF support service-side timeouts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974640/why-doesnt-wcf-support-service-side-timeouts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF has many timeouts...

- binding timeouts: SendTimeout, OpenTimeout and CloseTimeout (default 1 minute), ReceiveTimeout (default 10 minutes)
- service host: OpenTimeout (default 1 minute), CloseTimeout (default 10 seconds)
- reliable session inactivity timeout: default 10 minutes
- anything that inherits ConnectionOrientedTransportBindingElement e.g. NetTcp: ChannelInitializationTimeout default 30 seconds

My guess is that you have gotten "Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of ...." - this means that proxy has timed out waiting for service to send a response.

*"how this happens? [that service keep logging even if you have a "operation did not complete" timeout]"*

ServiceHost has allocated a thread to process the request made to the LongRunnerMethod method. This thread will finish processing the request until something catastrophic (e.g. process host shutdown) or exception is raised from inside a method.

*"is there a way to stop that [interrupt the thread processing the method call]?"*

You would need to get the signal from external source that you need to check on every n-th iteration to see if you should continue. You would need to pass something from the client in a form of unique id (ticket) to the first method then use this id with a Cancel method that will set the signal for the LongRunnerMethod to abort processing.

Here is an example using msmq which allows true one-way call:

SERVER

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddress = "net.msmq://localhost/private/";
            var address = "ILongRunner";

            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof (LongRunner), new Uri(baseAddress));
            var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None);
            var se = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ILongRunner), binding, address );
            se.VerifyQueue(); //comes from IDesign ServiceModelEx http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1887
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class LongRunner : ILongRunner
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentBag<Guid> Cancelations = new ConcurrentBag<Guid>();

        public void CancelLongRunnerMethod(Guid id)
        {
            if (Cancelations.All(z => z != id))
                Cancelations.Add(id);
        }

        public void LongRunnerMethod(Guid id)
        {
            int counter = 300000;

            //concurrent write will require different technique
            var file = string.Format(@"D:\log.{0}.txt", id);

            for (int i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                //check every 5th call
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    if (Cancelations.Any(z => z == id))
                    {
                        Guid cancelationId;

                        Cancelations.TryTake(out cancelationId);

                        if (cancelationId == id)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("LongRunnerMethod {0} canceled", id));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.WriteLine("at " + i);
                if (i >= counter)
                    break;
                var text = string.Format("{0} {1} \n", i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
                File.AppendAllText(file, text);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Complete " + id);
        }


    }

    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface ILongRunner
    {
         [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void CancelLongRunnerMethod(Guid id);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void LongRunnerMethod(Guid id);
    }
```

CLIENT

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddress = "net.msmq://localhost/private/";
            var address = "ILongRunner";


            var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None);
            var c1 = new ChannelFactory<ILongRunner>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(baseAddress + address)));
            var proxy = c1.CreateChannel();
            var request1 = Guid.NewGuid();
            proxy.LongRunnerMethod(request1);
            var co = c1 as ICommunicationObject;
            co.Close();


            var c2 = ChannelFactory<ILongRunner>.CreateChannel(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(baseAddress + address)));
            var request2 = Guid.NewGuid();
            c2.LongRunnerMethod(request2);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            var c3 = new ChannelFactory<ILongRunner>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(baseAddress + address)));
            var proxy2 = c3.CreateChannel();
            proxy2.CancelLongRunnerMethod(request1);
            var co2 = c3 as ICommunicationObject;
            co2.Close();
        }
    }
```